# find alfresco nodeRef without using luceneSearch

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have a js webscript who return a list of documents from a specific repository in Alfresco. i used the `luceneSearch` to get the `nodeRef` of the repository, this works fine.
The repository primary path is: `/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:StarXpert_x0020_Workflow/cm:fichiers_x0020_JSON` and i used the `luceneSearch` like this to get the nodeRef from the `primary path`

```
var nodes = search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:StarXpert_x0020_Workflow/cm:fichiers_x0020_JSON//*\" AND TYPE:\"cm:content\"","@cm:name", true);
```

But when i execute my code in the server side, i have an error, that my webScript can't get the nodes from the path i took it. I searched and i found that the problem is an indexation problem on the server alfresco version. 
So my question is: can us get a `nodeRef` from a primary path, whithout using `luceneSearch`?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's the error in question?

Comment: The Alfresco installed in the server don't accept the `LuceneSearch`, so i want to get a `nodeRef` from its `primary path` without using `LuceneSearch`

Comment: Why not walk your way down the path doing getChild to get each element?

Comment: How do you mean doesn't accept Lucene? Can you execute CMIS, FTS? What version of Alfresco is that?

Comment: The Alfresco version is 5.2.1. So when i execute a lucene search i still getting this error `Failed to execute search: PATH:"/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:StarXpert_x0020_Workflow/cm:fichiers_x0020_JSON//*" AND TYPE:"cm:content"` who is the PATH i used in the LuceneSearch. But when i execute the same Search with the same PATH in my local Alfresco it's working fine, i searched for, and i found out that the problem is that the Alfresco in the server side don't accept the LuceneSearch.

Comment: I think, the issue is to use the cmis, but i don't know how to use cmis in a webscript to get a list of repository documents. If you know how to manage this, it'll be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand [the documentation](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/Search.html), you can use other methods with the search root object. The [xpathSearch](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/Search.html#xpathSearch-java.lang.String-) seems interesting :

```
org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable xpathSearch(String search)
Execute a XPath search
```

The **selectNodes(String search)** might be interesting too.

Comment: i saw this, but the problem is that, this method don't allow to use the primary path to find the node

Comment: Is it the same that for the query(Object search) method (you can specify xpath language) ?

Comment: Ok, so, the Xpath is the same that the primary path??